# SP2013: Get item by id from javascript function?

Tags: 2013, display-template

I have built a display template. In the item template I have some Images from the list "Employees". I have created a function to get some detail info. In this function I have one parameter with the id from the selected item from "Employees". Now I would like to get an item from another list "EmployeeDetailInfo". In this list there is a lookup field to the "Employees" list. I would like to get an item from this list by the listItemID. How can I do this in a function?

```
function GetDetailInfo(itemID) {
   [some logic to get item from the list "EmployeeDetail"]
   var title = .....
   alert(title);
}
```

Comment: Does the listItemID which you have belong to "Employees" list or "EmployeeDetailInfo" list. Also, what is the name of the lookup field in "EmployeeDetailInfo" list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this function from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246019%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

```
  //Get the list item from the Announcements list whose Id is 4. Note that this is the ID of the item in the list, not a reference to its position in the collection.
   var itemId = 4;   
   var targetListItem;

   function runCode() {
     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(); 
     var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');
     targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(itemId);
     clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'Title');
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
   }

   function onQuerySucceeded() {

       alert('Request succeeded. \n\nRetrieved Item is: ' + targetListItem.get_item('Title'));

   }

   function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
     alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
   }
```

Change list name 'Announcements' and item id '4' to yours.

Comment: Thanks mate, this work. How can I get an listitem by lookupfield value? Something like, get item where column X is equal to value "2". Column x is a lookup field.

Comment: To get value from lookup field you need do something like this currentItem.get_item('X').get_lookupValue(). So all you need are getting all items (including only your 'X' field) and then go thru all this items and check, that field value eq '2' in your case.

Comment: Hi, this is great. May I know how to get multiple column values at a time. Like title, description etc...

Answer (score 4):

You need to use **JSOM** or **REST** to get the item. This in return means you must implement some kind of asynchronous behavior in `GetDetailInfo`.

For example (usin jQuery ajax):

```
function GetDetailInfo(itemID, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('EmployeeDetailInfo')/Items/getById(" + itemID + ")", 
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json; odata=verbose"
     }
   }).success(callback);
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
GetDetailInfo(1, function(item) {
   // work with item
});
```

This approach should work fine in display templates, and we have done this before without issues. Although note that this approach will create 1 REST call for each line, you could think of some way to get around that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Only for de new SharePoint BD developers, you can use the two answers in this post, both are correct, but know the difference:

1. Using JSOM request (Java Script Object Model). You use the list as a real database. With NO LIMIT. You use the typical READ / GET atomic operation. But its easier with JSON.
   Official documentation here: [Microsoft link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj246019(v=office.15))
2. Using JSON request (Java Script Object Notation) its easier than JSOM, but you can only access an item if the list has a maximun of 5000 items. Its the limit established by Microsoft. If the list has more than 5000 items, the request sent you an error. Check it out: [Sharepoint list limit](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)